# Getting complete and exact definition of a Django model attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose that I have `User` model as this:

```
class User(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
  password = models.CharField(min_lengj)
  connections = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, default=0, blank=False)
  ...   (other attributes)
```

For a special use case I need to know the exact definition of its fields
so I can get definition of connections as a `DecimalField` with `max_digits` equal
to 3 and `default` equal to `0` and cannot be `blank`.
How I can acheieve this?

Comment: You wrote it very well, what is your confusion?

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to access the field configuration from somewhere outside the model? If so, it would help to show us where you are trying to access this information and what you have tried.

Comment: @MKPatel @Nathan Clement The `User` model is just a hypothetical one, more real model is a dynamic model that user based on user input can have many more fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the fields with `User._meta.get_fields()` which returns a tuple of the fields defined for that model. You can furthermore use `User._meta.get_field('connections')` to obtain a specific field.

This will be a `DecimalField` object, with `'connections'` as its name. You can inspect attributes like `.name`, and `.max_digits` (that will return `3`).

You can furthermore use the [**`.deconstruct()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.deconstruct) to obtain a 4-tuple for that field that will contain: (1) the name of the field; (2) the type of the field as a string; (3) the positional parameters as a list; and (4) the named parameters as a dictionary.

So for your `User` model, we can see:

```
>>> User._meta.get_field('connections').deconstruct()
('connections', 'django.db.models.DecimalField', [], {'default': 0, 'max_digits': 3})
>>> User._meta.get_field('connections').blank
False
>>> User._meta.get_field('connections').max_digits
3
```